# need a fast way to make a calculation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to reshape the following matrix via a vector like this.
without for loop.

[image]

. To make the matrix, I need to put the elements of the vector in the same order, and then I shift one element and write it again.

Answer (score 4):

Just use indices and then reshape

```
mymat = reshape(myvec([1:5 2:6 3:7]),[],3);
```

To automate a bit further

```
myvec = 99:-1:80; % Some vector 
number_of_columns = 4;
window_length = 5;

ind = kron(ones(number_of_columns,1),[1:window_length]') + ...
    kron([0:number_of_columns-1]',ones(window_length,1));
Mymat = reshape(myvec(ind),[],number_of_columns);
```

Comment: Is it possible to make that solution generic for different input arrays?

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau Added some more detail

Answer (score 1):

The **naïve implementation** would use a simple loop and array slicing such as:

```
tab = ['x' 'y' 'z' 'w' 't' 'k' 'l']'
w = 3 
n = length(tab)
output = []
for i = 1:n - w +1 
  output(i,:) = tab(i:i+w-1)'
end
```

You can also avoid loops using the **hankel** matrixes.

```
tab = ['x' 'y' 'z' 'w' 't' 'k' 'l']'
n = length(tab)
w = 3

han = hankel(1:length(tab), 1:3)

output = []
arrayfun(@(x) tab(x),han(1:n-w+1,:))
```

But, if you wan't a really fast implementation, you can use sliding windows functionnal mapping from the image processing palette such as **colfilt**.